# Outlook Add-in 2013 - Animated Gif images in the ribbon

Tags: visual-studio-2012, outlook-addin, ribbon-control

I'm developing an Outlook Add-in in Visual studio 2012 (.NET 4.5). To present information to our users I need to display an button in a custom ribbon whose image is an animated gif.

Thus far I have done the following:

1) Added the animated GIF to my projects resources 
2) Add a button which calls a local method 'GetImage'
3) GetImage returns a Bitmap object from resources representing the GIF image.

When I launch the add-In the image loads but doesn't animate it just remains static. My question is does the outlook ribbon support animated gifs and if so what am I missing?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlook does not supports GIFs, much less animated GIFs, on the ribbons.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dmitry. I eventually figured this out! it's unfortunate that Outlook doesn't have this support as it would allow you to create a nicer front end experience.